# Java throws keyword

Tags: java, oop, exception

I accidentally declared a method that throws an exception, (`IllegalArgumentException`), but I forgot to use `throws`.
I thought it's mandatory, and I wondered why the code compiled without any warning / error.
If it's not mandatory, then what is the purpose of it?

Comment: That's because it's a `java.lang.RuntimeException`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: A method doesn't have to declare in its throws clause any subclasses of `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot throw a **checked** exception that isn't allowed by the `throws` clause. `IllegalArgumentException`, however, is a **runtime exception**, can you don't have to declare it.

Comment: You _can_ throw checked exceptions without matching throws clauses. It is just not as simple and requires a helper function with a generic throws clause.

Answer (score 1):

There are two (four) kinds of `Throwable`s in Java.

1. Plain `Exception`s (and subclasses): You need to catch them or declare throws at the message signature
2. `RuntimeException`s (and subclasses): As the name suggests, these happen because something fails at runtime (method call on null for example). These can be declared but don't have to (and some static code analysis tools complain if you do so). They can and should be caught somewhere.
3. `Error`s (and subclasses): These happen is something out of scope of the current code goes wrong (`OutOfMemoryError` for example). These shouldn't be caught because you can't do anything with them...
4. as @kaya stated `Throwable` itself: Should neither be thrown or caught.

Comment: What would be a better approach - always declaring methods with the `throws` keyword?

Comment: Technically, there is also `Throwable` itself, which isn't abstract, so you can `throw new Throwable();`.

Comment: @Lior That's opinon based and there are quite a few heated discussions about the use of checked and unchecked Exceptions in Java... Best to make up your own mind.